# UWP One to many binding

Tags: xaml, uwp, binding

i'm building venue navigation app, so i have two views, one is a list of possible destinations and the second is an jpg image with markers on top, so problem is:

on my model:

```
public class NavigationItem
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Icon{get; set;}
   public List<Vector2> Location {get; set;}
}
```

on my viewmodel:

```
{
  public List<NavigationItem> NavigationItems {get; set;}
}
```

now the xaml part

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
    <Image Source="map.jpg/>
    <winui:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItems}">
      <DataTemplate>
       <!-- And that's where the question is.... 
            I can't just do Image Source Binding, because location is List<Vector2>-->
      </DataTemplate>
   </winui:ItemsRepeater>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So, i thought to make another items repeater nested in first one, but i have no clue how to propagate Image Source to it like so:

```
<winui:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItems}">
   <DataTemplate>
       <winui:ItemsRepeater DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Location}" >
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:NavigationItemModel">
               <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </winui:ItemsRepeater>
    </DataTemplate>
</winui:ItemsRepeater>
```

All i get just bunch of binding errors, guess i'll just a user control and spawn all the crap in code behind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind the Image Source with the Icon property, you need to change the DataContext of Image to the DataContext of the second ItemsRepeater. So you can subscribe the **ElementPrepared** event from ItemsRepeater which means this event occurs each time an element is made ready for use. So when triggered this event, you can change the DataContext of Image in it.

.xaml:

```
<winui:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItems}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <winui:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding Location}" ElementPrepared="ItemsRepeater_ElementPrepared">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </winui:ItemsRepeater>
    </DataTemplate>
</winui:ItemsRepeater>
```

.cs:

```
private void ItemsRepeater_ElementPrepared(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsRepeater sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsRepeaterElementPreparedEventArgs args)
{
    var repeaterDataContext = sender.DataContext;
    Image MyImage = args.Element as Image;
    MyImage.DataContext = repeaterDataContext;
}
```

Comment: Hi, now the error is Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Icon' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.Numerics.Vector2'

Guess the problem is that second ItemsRepeater is already a Vector2 context, maybe i can declare a static resource and pass it down...

Comment: I haven't received this issue, [here](https://github.com/wcj233/ItemsRepeaterApp) is the simple sample you can download and check it. If you still receive this issue, please provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example, really appreciate your time, I still struggle with sorting this out on my project, did't manage to find any actual difference... but example project works just fine for me